# How to sync changes on my local server with the ones on the remote one without commiting?

Tags: git, github, version-control, version, development-environment

I'm developing some software that requires me to use a remote server for testing if it works. I can't host a local version.

Anyway, I have git set up. The way I work right now is I will change something locally on my Windows-based laptop, add a small git commit like "Fix", push it to the remote repository and then fetch it on the development server ( which runs a linux without GUI ).

I don't want to do that becase:

- The git history is littered with small pointless commits.
- It's tedious to have to create comits, push them to the remote repo
  and then fetch them from the developer server.

So I'm wondering - how should I set up the environment so that any change on my local laptop, even without commiting anything, make the files on the development server change instantly? Is there a way to do it? I can even skip sending it to the remote git server, I just want to sync files between my local machine and the development server.

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good practice to separate:

- source code management (including the act of committing, which, in your case, should not happen at *every* little change)
- release management (packaging and deployment)

> I can even skip sending it to the remote git server, I just want to sync files between my local machine and the development server.

That is a release management process, like having a cron job doing regular rsync. But it has nothing to do with your SCM (here: Git), which won't have a native solution for that.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **17000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 103 months), less than 6 months after the [160000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698777/6309). Before that, [150000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309) [140000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327286/6309). Before that, [13000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31640408/6309). [12000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28412501/6309); [11000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821796/6309), [10000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23909654/6309),, ...