# Cleartool commands in CCRC server side?

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-remote-client

Am using Clearcase Remote Client(CCRC) and do not have admin rights. Original Clearcase supports 'cleartool' command line interface where as CCRC uses 'rcleartool'. Now, there are some trigger scripts to be placed at the vob level by the admin. Whether at the server side, 'cleartool' commands will work or 'rcelartool'? Only for the client it will be'rcleartool' instead of 'cleartool'?

Answer (score 1):

> there are some trigger scripts to be placed at the vob level by the admin.

That would use the [mktrtype command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrtype.htm), which is a `cleartool` only command (not `rcleartool` version)

Even the [client-side `mktrigger`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktrigger.htm) has no rcleartool equivalent.

On the server side, an admin would have access to cleartool and can use those two commands.

Comment: `On the server side, an admin would have access to cleartool and can use those two commands.` Sorry little confused- how admin will have access to cleartool. If admin has cleartool access, trigger scripts would work with cleartool command then?

Comment: @Ravi trigger script will be executed on the server side, and setup on the server side. They will be triggered by events initiated from the client side. Your trigger scripts can therefore use `cleartool` commands.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **22000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 131 months), 6 months after the [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309). Before that, [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), [19000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421565/6309), [18000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860745/6309), [17000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703956/6309), [16000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698777/6309), [15000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309) [14000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327286/6309), ...

Answer (score 0):

It is especially important to note that -- in the case of web and automatic views -- triggers **do not** execute on the "client" host. They execute on the WAN server. This places a number of limitations on what the triggers can do. For example, all interaction has to be through "clearprompt" commands as interactive triggers are not otherwise supported in web and automatic views.

TO directly answer the question as I read it, the triggers would

- have to be placed using cleartool commands at the WAN server or some other LAN client.
- need to use cleartool commands (or some other LAN-client API) to query ClearCase and not "rcleartool."
- would need to ensure that any interactive elements detect they are running beneath the WAN server (CCASE_WEB_GUI EV set to 1), and use clearprompt as appropriate.

Comment: So, since the triggers would be placed at the WAN server using cleartool commands- triggers would work with cleartool commands itself: is this understanding correct?

Comment: If you mean "cleartool commands run elsewhere also fire triggers": Yes. If you mean "triggers CONTAINING cleartool commands will work," also yes.