# How can I use git bash aliases in vscode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have several git bash aliases that work fine when I use the git bash terminal, but they dont when I use the vscode integrated terminal? Is there a way to fix this? I do have bash selected in vscode.

After running `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope`

```sh
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslbackend=openssl
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig credential.helper=manager
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.editor=nano.exe
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.autocrlf=true
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.fscache=true
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig core.symlinks=true
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.clean=git-lfs clean -- %f
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
system  file:C:/Program Files/Git/etc/gitconfig filter.lfs.required=true
global  file:C:/Users/jgilr/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.smudge=git-lfs smudge -- %f
global  file:C:/Users/jgilr/.gitconfig  filter.lfs.process=git-lfs filter-process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how VSCode is launched.

Depending on your OS, it could be launched with a different account (or, on Windows, the "System" account), which means it would not benefit from the same "`git config --global -l`" settings, because its `HOME` environment variable is different from your bash.

In VSCode integrated terminal, assuming a recent Git, you can launch, to check if you see your aliases:

```
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
```

The solution is:

- add the aliases in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`
- use the [Shell argument](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_shell-arguments) `-l` (`--login`) for the setting "`terminal.integrated.shellArgs.linux`", as shown in [issue 7263](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/7263#issuecomment-224207986)

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/4ee75b50a8a0476ba28f8b84291a46be7595997c/68747470733a2f2f636c6475702e636f6d2f366c515065614377634a2e706e67]

Comment: I updated this post with what I got after running the command

Comment: @jgil I don't see any alias in those settings: VSCode does not run with the same user as you do. Or those alaises were define inside a repository.

Comment: is there a way to change it? I put in all my aliases in ```"C:\Program Files\Git\etc\profile.d\aliases.sh"```

Comment: @jgil Try putting those same aliases in `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`, then relaunch VSCode.

Comment: I see, I got it to work, I had to add the aliases to ```%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig``` and ```terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login"]``` to vscode settings

Comment: Note to self: That was my **24000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 142 months), less than 6 months after the [23000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853332/63099). Before that: [22000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387243/6309), [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309), [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), [19000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421565/6309), [18000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860745/6309), [17000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703956/6309), ...

Answer (score 2):

Issue was fixed by adding `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login"]` to vscode settings and writing all my aliases to %USERPROFILE%.bash_profile