# ssh config file and username for cyberark

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-config, cyber-ark

I'm trying to setup host in .ssh/config file with specified username. The problem is - this is ssh connection to cyberark host.

so - with this command I can connect to the target host:

```
ssh user1@user2@ip1@ip2
```

or with this command - works as well:

```
ssh ip2 -l user1@user2@ip1
```

but, I cannot connect when using this configuration in `.ssh/config` :

```
Host targethost
  Hostname ip2
  User user1@user2@ip1
```

Then when I try `ssh targethost`, I have connection timeout. I tried to put username into quotes, but this didn't help as well.

Any idea?

**[EDIT:]**

Output of `ssh -Tv`

```
$ ssh -Tv ip2
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/user_profile/ssh_config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 14: Applying options for ip2
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ip2 [x.x.x.x] port 22.
```

And then it is hanging

`/etc/ssh/ssh_config` from line 58:

```
Host *
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
        SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

Comment: While you asked for an `.ssh/config` and VonC's answer seems to work, I found it quite limiting to create a new configuration for each server since the User field does not allow token, thus I created a workaround for myself: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73665337/2010467

Answer (score 0):

It should work through `config` (as [confirmed here](https://jamersan.com/terminal-commands-username-sign/)), provided you use the right entry for "username":

```
Host targethost
  Hostname ip2
  User user1@user2@ip1  <====
```

It should be `User`, not `Username`.
See "[SSH Config File Example](https://linuxize.com/post/using-the-ssh-config-file/#ssh-config-file-example)" for illustration.

Comment: Note to self: That was my **25000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 147 months), less than 6 months after the [24000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62688871/6309). Before that:  [23000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59853332/63099), [22000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387243/6309), [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309), [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), [19000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421565/6309), [18000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860745/6309), ...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in description. I have indeed `User` in my config. Anyway it is not working for me. Typing ssh command with username directly to shell works, but looks like doesn't read user name from config for this particular configuration.

Comment: @robson Can you try `ssh -Tv targethost` to check what ssh is doing?

Comment: Please see update of my post with output of ssh -Tv command, thanks

Comment: @robson What is the option in line 58 of `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: @robson Just for testing, can you try without  those global '`*`' options, removing that section from your `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: but this is not my local config - but global one /etc/ssh/ssh_config, and I'm not allowed to change that (lack of permissions). In my local config there is just this entry at line 14 described above (for the Host targethost)

Comment: @robson system config, right. For testng, can you confirm that another remote user account, one *without* any `@` in it, would work?

Comment: yes, for other hosts not related to CyberArk and standard username works

Comment: @robson Is is possible to confirm that is works with a standard name on the same host?

Comment: yes, I have some entries for other hosts and it is working fine