# How to use openssh-client in Cyberark environments with autocompletion and multiple servers?

Tags: openssh, cyber-ark

I usually have what I need in my `~/.ssh/` folder (a `config` file and more) to connect to servers with `ssh <tab><tab>`. In an environment with Cyberark the configuration seems to be a bit more intricate due to the [three @ signs](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/latest/en/Content/PASIMP/PSSO-PMSP.htm#The)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65370954/2010467), but I struggled to find a way to enjoy autocompletion for many hosts because the `User` field does not support tokens like `%h` for host, so I'd have to create the same entry again for every server where I previously just added servers to the Host line. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time I came up with the following solution which is more like a workaround. I'm not really proud of it, but it gets the job done with the least amount of new code or difficult to understand code.

Create a wrapper script like this:

```bash
$  cat ~/bin/ssh-wrapper.sh
#!/bin/bash
# https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/PAS/latest/en/Content/PASIMP/PSSO-PMSP.htm#The
# Replace where appropriate:
# $1 = Server FQDN
# prefix = your administrative user may be different from you normal user
# internal.example.org = domain server (controller)
# pam.example.org = Cyberark jump host

ssh -t ${USERNAME,,}@prefix${USERNAME,,}#internal.example.org@$1@pam.example.org
```

Add the following to your bash startup file. Yours may be different than mine, because I'm hacking here in a customer environment with Tortoise Git-Bash. (Which works nice by the way when you use it with Flux Terminal, k9s and jq.)

1. Create an alias for you wrapper script, I chose `sshw` here.
2. Create variable with all the FQDNs of the servers you want to have in your autocompletion, or create file which contains these FQDNs and read it to a variable.
3. Create a bash completion expression which applies this to your `sshw` alias.

```bash
$  cat ~/.bash_profile
alias sshw="$HOME/bin/ssh-wrapper.sh"
SSH_COMPLETE=$(cat "$HOME/.ssh/known_hosts_wrapper")
complete -o default -W "${SSH_COMPLETE[*]}" sshw
```

Now you can tab you way to servers.