# How to Dockerize windows application

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization

i have a windows application which I want to containerize. Its a windows desktop application (not web application). I did some searching and found very little about containerizing desktop application. The application which I want to containerize works fine on WindowsServerCore. I have Windowsservercore image on my machine.

I want to know how can I go about containerizing it. Any documentation or useful videos are available?
when i completed dockerfile can i interact with my application gui??? how???

Comment: @mel thanks english isnt my natural language sorry. i edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find tons of example of WindowsServiceCore-based applications in [`StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows`](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows)

You need to write a Dockerfile (like for instance [`diskspd/Dockerfile`](https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/blob/master/diskspd/Dockerfile) where you copy/unzip/install the application you need.

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1770

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV DISKSPD_VERSION 2.0.17

RUN Invoke-WebRequest $('https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/DiskSpd-a-robust-storage-6cd2f223/file/152702/1/Diskspd-v{0}.zip' -f $env:DISKSPD_VERSION) -OutFile 'diskspd.zip' -UseBasicParsing ; \
    Expand-Archive diskspd.zip -DestinationPath C:\ ; \
    Remove-Item -Path diskspd.zip ; \
    Remove-Item -Recurse armfre ; \
    Remove-Item -Recurse x86fre ; \
    Remove-Item *.docx ; \
    Remove-Item *.pdf

ENTRYPOINT [ "C:\\amd64fre\\diskspd.exe" ]
```

That being said, a full GUI support for windowscoreserver is still requested:
"[Create base container with full GUI support"](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/304624-containers/suggestions/13785024-create-base-container-with-full-gui-support).

Comment: i want to know when i complete dockerfile can i run it in vmware? can i interact with my application gui???

Comment: @DrSima no gui yes, I believe: see my edited answer. What is your hhost for your VMWare?

Comment: Note to self: That was my **18000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 109 months), less than 7 months after the [170000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703956/6309) . Before that, [160000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698777/6309), [150000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309) [140000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34327286/6309), [13000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31640408/6309). [12000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28412501/6309); [11000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25821796/6309), ...